# Right margin in table cells aligned to the right in Latex

Tags: latex, tabular

I have the following table in Latex[image]

Created with this code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{aaaa}
\label{tab:treatments}
\centering
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\toprule

\tabhead{Por 1} & \tabhead{Por 3}  & \tabhead{Quantificazione log-dim} & \tabhead{cintin\'a}  \\
\midrule
A & M & 99.3\%& 5.4\\
B& A &  2.0\%& 4.6\\
C & N & 5.8\% & 4.6\\
D & N & 3.5\% & 4.26\\
E & K & 22.5\% & 3.7\\
\bottomrule\\

\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

I would like to have the third column of percentages aligned to the right 
At the same time the column label is too large. If I aligned the column to the right it would and up visually weird.

In a Word table I would align the column to the right and than add a right margin to the cells. The numbers would move toward the cell center while keeping their alignment to the right.

How do I do that in Latex? How do I add a margin to the right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of options you can try:

- Original:

  [image]
- Multi-row header:

  [image]
- Manual alignment of centred columns using `\phantom`s:

  [image]
- Manual alignment of centred columns using `\eqmakebox`es (from [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)):

  [image]
- Automated alignment of centred columns using [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx):

  [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx,makecell,siunitx,eqparbox}
\newcommand{\tabhead}{\textbf}

\begin{document}

Original:

\begin{tabular}{ l c c c }
  \toprule
  \tabhead{Por 1} & \tabhead{Por 3}  & \tabhead{Quantificazione log-dim} & \tabhead{cintin\'a}  \\
  \midrule
  A & M & 99.3\% & 5.4  \\
  B & A &  2.0\% & 4.6  \\
  C & N &  5.8\% & 4.6  \\
  D & N &  3.5\% & 4.26 \\
  E & K & 22.5\% & 3.7  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Multi-row header:

\begin{tabular}{ l c c c }
  \toprule
  \tabhead{Por 1} & \tabhead{Por 3}  & \tabhead{\makecell[b]{Quantificazione \\ log-dim}} & \tabhead{cintin\'a}  \\
  \midrule
  A & M & 99.3\% & 5.4  \\
  B & A &  2.0\% & 4.6  \\
  C & N &  5.8\% & 4.6  \\
  D & N &  3.5\% & 4.26 \\
  E & K & 22.5\% & 3.7  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Manual alignment of centred columns using \verb|\phantom|s:

\begin{tabular}{ l c c c }
  \toprule
  \tabhead{Por 1} & \tabhead{Por 3}  & \tabhead{\makecell[b]{Quantificazione \\ log-dim}} & \tabhead{cintin\'a}  \\
  \midrule
  A & M & 99.3\% & 5.4\phantom{0}  \\
  B & A & \phantom{0}2.0\% & 4.6\phantom{0}  \\
  C & N & \phantom{0}5.8\% & 4.6\phantom{0}  \\
  D & N & \phantom{0}3.5\% & 4.26 \\
  E & K & 22.5\% & 3.7\phantom{0}  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Manual alignment of centred columns using \verb|\eqmakebox|es:

\begin{tabular}{ l c c c }
  \toprule
  \tabhead{Por 1} & \tabhead{Por 3}  & \tabhead{\makecell[b]{Quantificazione \\ log-dim}} & \tabhead{cintin\'a}  \\
  \midrule
  A & M & \eqmakebox[log][r]{99.3\%} & \eqmakebox[cint][l]{5.4}  \\
  B & A & \eqmakebox[log][r]{ 2.0\%} & \eqmakebox[cint][l]{4.6}  \\
  C & N & \eqmakebox[log][r]{ 5.8\%} & \eqmakebox[cint][l]{4.6}  \\
  D & N & \eqmakebox[log][r]{ 3.5\%} & \eqmakebox[cint][l]{4.26} \\
  E & K & \eqmakebox[log][r]{22.5\%} & \eqmakebox[cint][l]{3.7}  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\newpage

Automated alignment of centred columns using \verb|siunitx|:

\begin{tabular}{ l c S[table-format = 2.1, table-space-text-post = \%] S[table-format = 1.2] }
  \toprule
  \tabhead{Por 1} & \tabhead{Por 3}  & \tabhead{\makecell[b]{Quantificazione \\ log-dim}} & \tabhead{cintin\'a}  \\
  \midrule
  A & M & 99.3\% & 5.4  \\
  B & A &  2.0\% & 4.6  \\
  C & N &  5.8\% & 4.6  \\
  D & N &  3.5\% & 4.26 \\
  E & K & 22.5\% & 3.7  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```